# getElementsByName returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html

This is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var crct_answrs = new Array(<?php echo implode(',', $crct_ans); ?>);
    var answrs = new Array();

    function check_ans(){
        for(var i = 1; i < 11; i++){
            var tst = "ques"+i;
            var radio = document.getElementsByName(tst);
            for (var x = 0; x < radio.length; x ++) {
                if (radio[x].checked) {
                    answrs = radio.value;
                }   
            }
        }       
    }   
</script>
```

This is part of HTML:

```
<form>
            <div id="quest1" class="question">
                <div class="prblm">
                    <?php echo $questions[1]; ?></div>
                <table class="answrs">
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $answrs[1][1]; ?></td>
                        <td><input name="ques1" type="radio" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $answrs[1][2]; ?></td>
                        <td><input name="ques1" type="radio" value="2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $answrs[1][3]; ?></td>
                        <td><input name="ques1" type="radio" value="3"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $answrs[1][4]; ?></td>
                        <td><input name="ques1" type="radio" value="4"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

I have 10 same pattern `div` tags with tables and the `input` name is change accordingly. 
`check_ans()` runs on `onclick`. But all the time `getElementsByName` returns undefined. Why this happens. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: It does not return `undefined` for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jDx69/

Comment: Indeed, like @FelixKling said, `getElementsByname` should never return  `undefined`.

Comment: Shall i put my entire code here?

Comment: No, put the *relevant* code here. You can create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo with the whole code. And be precise with your error description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error lies in:

```
if (radio[x].checked) {
    answrs = radio.value;
}
```

`answrs` is an array and needs to set values to the index of the corresponding iterator it's on.  `radio.value` is trying to access value from the `radio` array, but has left out it's index as well.  Look at my solution below for the fix:

---

I've got a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9YprE/) working.

**JavaScript:**

```
var answrs = [];

function check_ans() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        var radio = document.getElementsByName("ques" + i);
        for (var x = 0; x < radio.length; x++) {
            if (radio[x].checked) {
                answrs[i-1] = radio[x].value;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(answrs);
}​
```

**Output:**

When selecting an answer 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4 for questions 1-10 the array is:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "3", "2", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Comment: I updated my answer with the explanation of your error at the top.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it going!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. This worked for me (I've removed some PHP code)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var crct_answrs = new Array();
    var answrs = new Array();

    function check_ans(){

        for(var i = 1; i < 11; i++){
            var tst = "ques"+i;

            var radio = document.getElementsByName(tst);
            alert(radio);
            for (var x = 0; x < radio.length; x ++) {
                if (radio[x].checked) {
                    answrs = radio.value;
                }   
            }
        }       
    }   
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="check_ans();">test</button>
            <div id="quest1" class="question">
                <div class="prblm">
                    <?php echo $questions[1]; ?></div>
                <table class="answrs">
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $answrs[1][1]; ?></td>
                        <td><input name="ques1" type="radio" value="1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $answrs[1][2]; ?></td>
                        <td><input name="ques1" type="radio" value="2"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $answrs[1][3]; ?></td>
                        <td><input name="ques1" type="radio" value="3"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $answrs[1][4]; ?></td>
                        <td><input name="ques1" type="radio" value="4"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

<body/>
</html>
```

Any differences from your code? alert call shows values.

Answer (score -1):

I sometimes get an undefined var assigned to `document.getElementsByName(name)`.

So I would try to see if any answers from the web would help.  Alas, nothing worked.

So I went ahead and tested the array I thought I should be getting. and the elements were there.  So just ignore the 'undefined' and proceed working with the var.

Comment: That's not really answering the question. Plus, as the accepted answer says, `document.getElementsByName` should never return `undefined`